# Java/JS library to detect (not validate) emails and/or phone numbers in text

Tags: library, javascript, java, email, phone

Is there any Java or Javascript library that deals with email/phone numbers detection within text? I'm not talking about validating them, just want to find something that could potentially look like an email address of a phone number.

We're trying to prevent users to send this kind of information through our platform.

Answer (score 1):

Just use regular expressions.

For an email address just use the regular expression for at least one letter or number followed by @ followed by at least one letter or number a dot and at least one more letter, so:
`a@b.c` could possibly be an email address as could `somereallylongname@company.com` ect. a possible re would be `\w+@\w\.\w`

Telephone numbers would be, depending on whether you are looking for long distance numbers only, something like `\d{2}[ -]*\d{3}[ -]*\d{3,}` but you might be better off locating potential phone numbers with a regex then using the google [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) java/JS library which is a much more sophisticated library for checking and validating phone numbers and allows you to check if something is a possible phone number and if it is a valid phone number.

Comment: As TLDs do have at least 2 chars, and 2nd level domains usually as well, one could improve the related regex to `[w\.]+@(\w{2,}\.)+\w{2,}` (to also take into account multilevel domains like `abc.xyz.com`). Phone numbers are a bit more tricky: from using formatting like `+1-123-55555-321` via `+1 (0123) 55555 321` to just `012355555321`, everything could be a phone number. As one cannot filter all `[0-9\+\-]*`, this would require a more sophisticated filter – which some library might already cover (so better use that than to re-invent the wheel).